# Package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet 1.0.0-msbuild2-final' has a package type 'DotnetCliTool' that is not supported by project

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

When I use Visual Studio 2017 RC  to create netcore project and Nuget Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet, but I get an error.

> Package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet
>   1.0.0-msbuild2-final' has a package type 'DotnetCliTool' that is not supported by project 'src\WebApplication1'.

How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Open your .csproj file and add the lines:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools"
    Version="1.0.0-msbuild2-final" />
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet"
    Version="1.0.0-msbuild2-final" />
```

Comment: Same works for 
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild3-final" />
  </ItemGroup>

Comment: same trick works for installing EF tools.dotnet for a console app i.e. `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet` fails (`package type 'DotnetCliTool' that is not supported ...`) but manually editing the .csproj and adding `<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.1" />` works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your project file and add these

```
<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet">
        <Version>1.0.0-msbuild3-final</Version>
    </DotNetCliToolReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

And than open visual studio's developer PowerShell editor and run these command

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet
```