# Package 'Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools 1.1.0-preview4-final' has a package type 'DotnetCliTool'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

FalconWebsite.csproj

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="knockoutjs" Version="3.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0-beta1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.1.0-msbuild3-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild3-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I am trying to install the Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools with the below command

Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools -Pre

However, I am getting as below image

[image: error details]

I found the similar error in this link [Package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet 1.0.0-msbuild2-final' has a package type 'DotnetCliTool' that is not supported by project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41397976/package-microsoft-entityframeworkcore-tools-dotnet-1-0-0-msbuild2-final-has-a)
But, not working for me as per the link

Comment: same problem here ! and I couldn't find anyone knows anything about it !
How can we approach this ?

Comment: I meet the same problem.VS 2017 Community Edition,Asp .Net Core Web projcet.I cannot solve it!

Answer (score 1):

Edit the project file, add the following line:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild3-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I just tried it and it worked.

Comment: It is a bug actually, and it is raised on this link:
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4190

Answer (score 0):

Use `Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools` version `1.0.0-msbuild3-final`

Comment: I got the same error. I used the command  " Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools -Version 1.0.0-msbuild3-final " . i tried to copy and paste the "<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild3-final" />". But still same problem

Answer (score 0):

Because of [NuGet/Home#4190](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4190), you cannot install the package from the NuGet GUI.Instead, you must edit your csproj file to contain:

```
<ItemGroup>
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild3-final" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Here is your answer,because I solve it by the page.
https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/issues/597